# Como faço um roteamento no Angular, da página de login para a tela e inicial e após isso, uma outra tela. Esse é o meu app-routing.module

Tags: angularjs, rotas, angular-module, routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'inicial',
    loadChildren: () => import('./inicial/inicial.module').then(m => m.InicialModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'adicionar',
    loadChildren: () => import('./inicial/inicial.module').then(m => m.InicialModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se percebi devidamente a sua dúvida, entretanto caso tenhas o teu roteamento devidamente definido deves ter o seguinte código no teu html da tela do login.

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-2" [routerLink]="['/inicial']" > Login</button>
```